# Ants moving on a chessboard eventually occupying the same square

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> In an $n\times n$ chessboard, $n>2$, $M$ squares have an ant in their center. Each ant starts moving with the same speed parallel to some edge of the chessboard. When they reach the center of the next square, they turn $90^{\circ}$ to the left or right and continue moving in that direction. The ants always choose their direction of turning so that they won’t fall off the edge of the board.
>
> What is the minimum value of $M$ so that we can guarantee that eventually there will be two ants on the same square?

This is a variant of [IMO Shortlist 2011 C5](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2011SL.pdf). I feel that the pigeonhole principle will be useful here, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

For $n$ even, it is possible to have $M=n^2$ ants without them ever occupying the same square, as per Max Freiburghaus' example in the comments below. For odd $n$, is $M=(n-1)^2+1$ the answer?

Comment: Did you mean $M = (n-1)^2 + 1$?

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus yes of course

Comment: I feel like the colouring (always moving from black to white) could help, working from the example that you probably had in mind with $(n-1)^2$ ants not clashing.

Comment: Is M the minimum over all starting configurations or the minimum for which there is a starting configuration that guarantees two ants meet?  I can do better in the second case.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan: I think the former as you're asked to give a bound without knowledge of the configuration.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes it is the minimum over all starting configurations

Comment: If $n$ is even, can't you have a full board with ants moving within 2 by 2 blocks?

Comment: @Smylic I don't think that works? Could you explain yourself more?

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus yes that works. Should I change the question to specify $n$ odd?

Comment: @Smylic: 3 by 3 doesn't work because the ants have to turn every step.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note.** After two moves each ant appears in a cell that has exactly one common corner with his current cell.

Suppose that ant can move infinitely long with no *collision* that is two ants in the same cell.

Let us enumerate both rows and columns one after another with numbers $1, \ldots, n$. If $n = 2k + 1$ then there are $k^2$ cells that have both coordinates even and these cells can contain up to $k^2$ ants. By note above we can deduce that there are also at most $k^2$ ants on cells with both coordinates odd. After one move each other ant (on a cell with an odd sum of coordinates) goes to a cell with even sum of coordinates that is one of considered above. This means that number of such ants is at most $2k^2$, too, that gives at most $4k^2 = (n - 1)^2$ ants in total.

Thus for $M = (n - 1)^2 + 1$ there definitely will be a collision.

Comment: Could you make the part "By note above ... both coordinates odd" a little more rigorous please?

Comment: For each cell with both coordinates odd all cells that have exactly one common corner with it have both coordinates even.

Comment: but how does that imply that there are an equal number of both?

Comment: I mean not equal numbers, but equal upper bounds. Let that are $M_o$ ants on cells with both coordinates odd. After two moves all these ants are on cells wtih both coordinates even. This means that $M_o \le k^2$.

Comment: sorry, I was being very stupid. Thanks.